# Not able to toggle property check box property using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i want to toggle disable property of a checkbox group based on other checkbox checked property
Html code for checkbox group is  is :

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
            <div class="col1">

              <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="backpack" id="backpack" tabindex="170" />
              <label for="backpack">Backpack Cal</label>
</p>
              <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="calm" id="calm" tabindex="180" />
              <label for="calm">California Calm</label>
</p>
              <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="hotsprings" id="hotsprings" tabindex="190" />
              <label for="hotsprings">California Hotsprings</label>
</p>        
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
              <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="cycle" id="cycle" tabindex="210" />
              <label for="cycle">Cycle California</label>
</p>
             <p>
 <input type="checkbox" name="desert" id="desert" tabindex="220" />
              <label for="desert">From Desert to Sea</label>
</p>
             <p>
 <input type="checkbox" name="kids" id="kids" tabindex="230" />
              <label for="kids">Kids California</label>
</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col3">
              <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="nature" id="nature" tabindex="240" />
              <label for="nature">Nature Watch</label>
</p>
              <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="snowboard" id="snowboard" tabindex="250" />
              <label for="snowboard">Snowboard Cali</label>
</p>
             <p>
 <input type="checkbox" name="taste" id="taste" tabindex="260" />
              <label for="taste">Taste of California</label>
</p>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Html code for toggle button is

```
<div id="group-toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" name="bike_check" id="bike_check" /> <label for="bike_check">I own, or will otherwise provide, my own bicycle</label>
            </div>
```

And jquery code  is

```
var $checkbox=  $('.checkbox-group').find('input[type=checkbox]');
$checkbox.prop('disabled',true);
$('#bike_check').click(function() {
var $toggle=$(this);
});

$checkbox.prop('disabled',!$toggle.prop('checked'));
```

i am able to do it using if-else statement but not by this ,what thing i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change one line

**Either**

Place

> $checkbox.prop('disabled',!$toggle.prop('checked'));

inside the *click handler* because you can't access `$toggle` variable outside the scope, so you've to do operation inside the click handler

```
$('#bike_check').click(function() {
    var $toggle=$(this);
    $checkbox.prop('disabled',!$toggle.prop('checked'));
});
```

**OR**

Declare `$toggle` variable outside the click handler and initialize it inside `click()`

### [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3uechmo/)